# using generated column in a MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

If I have a query, such as:

```
select column1, (
    select count(*) from table2
) as some_count
from table1
where column1 = 'foo'
```

I can use `column1` in the where clause, but if I try to add

```
and some_count > 0
```

then I get an error that `some_count` doesn't exist. How can I use that in a where clause?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

```
select column1, (
    select count(*) from table2
) as some_count
from table1
HAVING some_count > 0
```

Comment: MySQL & SQL Server support column alias referencing in GROUP BY & HAVING, but Oracle doesn't.  However, SQL Server would throw an error because neither column is wrapped in an aggregate or mentioned in a GROUP BY clause.  Only on MySQL and SQLite is this query valid, +1

Comment: That's perfect, this is for a wordpress site so it's running MySQL, though I'm glad to see the pitfalls about oracle and sql server

Answer (score 4):

As is, the only way is to use a derived table:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (select column1, 
               (select count(*) from table2) as some_count
          from table1
         where column1 = 'foo') x
 WHERE x.some_count > 0
```

Do you realize that without correlation, `some_count` is going to return the same value for every row returned?

Comment: yes, this is just a quick example. But I never thought (or knew how) of using a derived table. I'll give it a try